# HttpContext Current Server MapPath : not getting the correct path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Beginner: Need some help in figuring out how can we do it. I am using MVC4 controller with c# and this is happeing in one of my actions

I am trying to get the path of a config file which is located at

```
 c:\TestProj\www\config\config.xml
```

I am using this to get the path

```
var expectedPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\config\config.xml")
```

but when i run my action what i am getting in my expected path is

```
 c:\Test\www\config\config.xml
```

I am not sure why..can some one please make some suggestions

Comment: Source folder and published/virtual folder are different. Can you tell us how are you running the app? From Visual Studio or have you published the app?

Answer (score 0):

~ represents the application path.

May be your application is located on c:\Test\www.
Either place config.xml on C:\test\www\config\config.xml 
or move your application to the C:\testproj folder
or use a different method instead of MapPath, that uses absolute path.

Comment: ran some more scans and all the folders were pointing and had correct physical paths except this one which was pointing incorrectly to C:\Test.. Just changed it and it seems to be fine..thanks guys